# C++ Template function and define particular cases

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create some particular cases of a template function (is there a name for this?). However, the following code gives me 'does not define a type' error.

(Due to reasons, I need a function that returns a map of a certain object.)

```
template <class T>
std::map<std::string, T> iniObj(){std::map<std::string, T> b; return b;}

using iniMyObj = iniObj<myObj>;
```

Comment: My bad. Those were not in the original code. I've edited the original post. Thanks!

Comment: `myObj` has to be a type.

Comment: AFAIK you can't use 'using' with a function. You can use 'using' to create _type aliases_ or _alias templates_. You probably want partial specialization for functions, but that does not exist in C++, so instead you can delegate to a partially specialized class from within your function 'initObj'.

EDIT: Or maybe you just want _full template specialization_. Or maybe you just want to create a new function iniMyObj that delegates to iniObj<myObj>. Maybe you can elaborate more in your question exactly what it is you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure `myObj` is defined. The following code works for me:

```
auto M = iniObj<int>();
```

The problem could also be related with making use of the `using` keyword with incomplete template type. You can try using a macro ..it works!

```
#define iniMyObj iniObj<int>
```